# Can't compile restbed on Windows 7

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake

I'm a the end with 16 hours of configure, installing, deleting, modifying and hit my keyboard many times....

I want to use [restbed](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed%20restbed) for plattform independent C++ programming, but I can't get build this stuff. I have Cygwin (download at 2017/04/24) installed (think for git or whatever creepy things), Code::Blocks with MinGW (16.01) and at least a seperate MinGW (also downloaded 2017/04/24) installation. Also I've Visual Studio 2012 Pro, 2015 and 2017 (long story) on a Windows 7 x64 Pro.

This is what I try and the results:
cloning recursivly with git in empty directory and following the instructions.

```
cmake -DBUILD_TESTS=YES -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=YES -DBUILD_SSL=NO -DBUILD_SHARED=YES ..
```

Uhh.. success. I seems it using the gcc/g++ from Cygwin.

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
:
:
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /cygdrive/d/Entwicklung/C++/restbed/restbed/build
```

Nice! Now follows:

```
make -j install
```

After 7% working, it gives a bunch of warnings and failed:

```
/cygdrive/{my_path_to}/restbed/restbed/dependency/asio/asio/include/asio/detail/config.hpp:755:5: warning: #warning Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. [-Wcpp]
 #   warning Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately.
     ^
/cygdrive/{my_path_to}/restbed/restbed/dependency/asio/asio/include/asio/detail/config.hpp:756:5: warning: #warning For example, add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line. [-Wcpp]
 #   warning For example, add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 to the compiler command line.
     ^
/cygdrive/{my_path_to}/restbed/restbed/dependency/asio/asio/include/asio/detail/config.hpp:757:5: warning: #warning Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target). [-Wcpp]
 #   warning Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 (i.e. Windows XP target).
     ^
/cygdrive/{my_path_to}/restbed/restbed/dependency/asio/asio/include/asio/detail/config.hpp:781:5: error: #error You must add -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS to your compiler options.
```

I modifing config.hpp and add

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#endif
```

The 'define bla' warnings dissapear, but now I should set '-D__USE_W32_SOCKETS'.

BUT WHERE?

After researching google I try to set a enviroment variable CPPFLAGS=-D__USE_W32_SOCKETS, but this change nothing!

OK, now I want give MinGW a chance, but how get I rid of this penetrant Cygwin, without deinstalling and get mess with other software?

Cool, should I set some enviroment variables....
Clean up the build-Directory and set CC and CXX as mentioned in cmake output.

```
SET CC=D:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
SET CXX=D:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
```

Checking my PATH variable and adding ";D:\MinGW\mysys\1.0\bin;D:\MinGW\bin"

Now use cmake bla.. again...but... but... WHAT?

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    D:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    D:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/{my_path_to}/restbed/restbed/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

With Cygwin cmake says, I use gcc/g++ in version GNU 5.4.0. On the other hand, it detects the correct MinGW version as 5.3.0, but can't find it? Hu?

What can I do to get this library work under Windows 7?

**EDIT BEGIN**

<s>To build makefiles for Code::Blocks, the -G parameter doesn't work. I try some combinations, but always say:</s>

```
cmake -DBUILD_TESTS=YES -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=YES -DBUILD_SSL=NO -DBUILD_SHARED=YES -G "CodeBlocks" ..
CMake Error: Could not create named generator CodeBlocks

Generators
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
:    
:
cmake -DBUILD_TESTS=YES -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=YES -DBUILD_SSL=NO -DBUILD_SHARED=YES -G "CodeBlocks - Ninja" ..
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

<s>Now this (many censored words) thing want to know the cmake-make?</s>

My fault.... don't think about, what I've installed.

"CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" works as expected for generating project file, but can't compile under Code::Blocks. I changed compiler for project in 'Build options' to Cygwin, but says:

```
Execution of '/usr/bin/make.exe -j8 -f "/cygdrive/d/{my_path_to}/restbed/restbed/build/Makefile"  VERBOSE=1 all' in 'D:\{my_path_to}\restbed\restbed\build' failed.
```

...and nothing more. Think it has to do with "Unix Makefile" under Windows.

**EDIT END**

I'm out of knowledge what to do, what to set, to delete, to modify, configure, aaaargh.

My last hope is, that someone has the big hint, a good idea or a workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: About the MinGW errors: Do not set CC or CXX or CMAKE_C_FLAGS, CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS. Instead make MinGW's gcc, g++ available in your path; i.e. set PATH=D:\MinGW\bin;%PATH%. And most importantly, call cmake with -G"MinGW Makefiles".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restbed can build with [Visual Studio 2015/2017](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/issues/17), why not use the native toolchain for that platform?

Comment: According to the restbed "readme", a c++11 compliant compiler is required. GCC 5.4.0 certainly is c++11 compliant so should work with a minimal cmake cmdline (in a MinGW environment)

Comment: The faults you have stated look environmental, not project related.  Raise a ticket on the GitHub issue tracker and will get to it when time permits; low priority due to availability of the native toolchain.